# Cheapest ride from Raja Ferry to Chaweng Beach

Tags: transportation

I have a question. Me and my girlfriend are going to Thailand and also Koh Samui in January. I am wondering which type of transport is best to take in Koh Samui and also in Thailand in general.

1) Is it best to book combined rides that take you from Surat Thani to Ferry dock to Koh Samui and than to any hotel on 12GO asia - https://12go.asia/en/travel/surat-thani-airport/koh-samui?date=2019-01-14&people=2&direction=forward or is it better to just book transportation from Surat Thani to Koh Samui and than take a taxi or Songthaews to a hotel in Chaweng Beach?

Thank you :)

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE.  I'm having some trouble identifying the specific question in there, could I ask you to narrow it down?